# recreate JinternalFrame object after dispose() call

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, dispose, jinternalframe

Situation: there is Supplier_JinternalFrame in JDesktopPane. A Supplier_button is available for call SetVisible(true) in JDesktopPane to show the Supplier frame. but when i close the Supplier Frame through Dispose(); its hide and never see again after click button again.
there is and option to use setshow(); and setHide() instead of setDispose(). but i want to recreate Jinternalframe instead of previous form. here is my Supplier_button code for call the Supplier_JInternalFrame Object.

```
  private void Suppliers_ButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)   {                                                 
    Suppliers_JinternalFrame.setVisible(true);//call the object of frame to show the frame
}
```

and in Suppliers_JinternalFrame Close button code

```
 private void Close_SupMangActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
   Suppliers.dispose();//To close the frame 
}
```

after click supplier_Button again. it never show frame again.
Any Idea, what should i do to recall the InternalFrame . Is there Any WindowEvents, i suggestest to create ?

Comment: It's likely that the `JInternalFrame` has been removed from the `JDesktopPane`, you may need to add it again and then make it visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `dispose` is called, the `JInternalFrame` is made invisible, it is also removed from the `JDesktopPane` (think `desktopPane.remove(...)`)

This means that making the frame visible again has no (visible) effect.  You need to add the frame back onto the `JDesktopPane`

Comment: where i should add frame , in Supplier_Button to call the frame again ?

Comment: @user3079252 That would be my guess

Comment: if (Customer.isClosed()){
                    Customer.setBounds(310, 110, 850, 460);
                jDesktopPane1.add(Customer,  javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

Comment: above code works but display the previous condition of frame not like new one. e-g previous data of textField in Frame remains there.

Comment: Okay. So, instead of re-adding a previously discarded internal frame, which seemed to be what you wanted, create a new instance `Suppliers_ButtonActionPerformed` is called and add that instead...